# (Swift) UIImageView not showing/invisible

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm just trying to draw an imageView and change it's image when a Button is pressed, but the imageView is not showing at all. No Errors, nothing. Even tho the Button works.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var menu_view: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "StartUpNoBack"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let menu_midbtn: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system) as UIButton
        menu_midbtn.frame = CGRect(x: 165, y: 318, width: 45, height: 40)
        menu_midbtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "penta"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        menu_midbtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
        menu_midbtn.tag = 1
        self.view.addSubview(menu_midbtn)


        menu_view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667)
        //menu_view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.addSubview(menu_view)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func openMenu(){
        menu_view.image = UIImage(named: "MenuOpen")
        menu_view.setNeedsDisplay()
        print("open menu")
    }

}
```

Comment: while you are initialising the imageView menu_view you are using "StartUpNoBack". Later when the button is pressed you are updating the image to "MenuOpen" right? Is the image atleast loaded with "StartUpNoBack" when the app is started and not getting updated to "Menuopen" when button is pressed? Also all the images are added in assets.xcassets or not?

Answer (score 0):

the highest possibility would be that the `UIImage(named:)` is failing to find the image and returning a nil.

But if I could make a suggestion. Switch to using a storyboard. Whilst doing code like this helps with understanding how things work, just about all of this can be handled within IB and missing images would be immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0):

As @drekka has answered that the `UIImageView` `menu_view` is not getting the image.

Add this line :

```
menu_view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

and you will not be able to touch the button too.

And this line :

```
menu_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
```

will tell you that `menu_view` is present in the view or not.

Answer (score 0):

Perform your layout related tasks such as setting frames in ,

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```